# PS7.1 - How do you use pipeline chaining with custom functions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

According to documentation, PS 7 has introduced pipeline chaining operators such as `||` and `&&`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7

And you should be able to do C#-style short circuiting operations like:

`Write-Error 'Bad' && Write-Output 'Second'`

The above examples work. And the documentation says that the pipeline chaining operators use two fields (unsure how that works precisely): `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE`

How do I apply these to my own functions?

For example:

```bsh
function yes() { 
  echo 'called yes'
  return $True 
}
function no() { 
  echo 'called no'
  return $False 
}
```

I feel like I should be able to run the following `no && yes` and see the following output

> called no
>
> False

but instead I see

> called no
>
> False
>
> called yes
>
> True

So how do I develop functions in such a way that I can use pipeline chaining and short circuiting?

edit: the only way I can figure out right now to construct a custom function that will short circuit an `&&` is to make it `throw`, but that doesn't seem too useful in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`&&` and `||` solely operate on the *success status*** of a command, as reflected in the [automatic **`$?`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) (as you state) - which is **unrelated to what a command *outputs*** (returns).

Functions and scripts report `$?` as `$true`, unless explicit action is taken; that is, even if commands used inside the script / function fail, `$?` is still `$true` when the script / function exits.

Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell 7.0, there is no direct way for a *function* to directly set `$?` to `$false`**, although the plan is to add such a feature - see [this GitHub isssue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490).

**In a *script*, using `exit` with a nonzero exit code is effective**, however (this causes `$LASTEXITCODE` to reflect the exit code, and the PowerShell engine sets `$?` to `$false` if the exit code is nonzero - this is also how it works when you call *external programs*).

---

For now, there's only the following **suboptimal workaround** for functions; it is suboptimal in that it *invariably emits an error message*:

```
function no { 
  # Make the function an advanced one, so that $PSCmdlet.WriteError()
  # can be called.
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  # Call $PSCmdlet.WriteError() with a dummy error, which
  # sets $? to $false in the caller's scope.
  # By default, this dummy error prints and is recorded in the $Error
  # collection; you can use -ErrorAction Ignore on invocation to suppress
  # that.
  $PSCmdlet.WriteError(
   [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
     [exception]::new(), # the underlying exception
     'dummy',            # the error ID
     'NotSpecified',     # the error category
     $null)              # the object the error relates to
  ) 
}
```

Function `no` now sets `$?` to false, which triggers a `||` branch; `-EA Ignore` (`-ErrorAction Ignore`) is used to silence the dummy error.

```
PS> no -EA Ignore || 'no!'
no!
```

Comment: Wow. Okay. It's a shame it's not supported yet. Thanks for the incredibly complete answer

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Kir; my pleasure. Agreed that it's high time to support this. `&&` and `||`, borrowed from POSIX-like shells, aren't a great fit for native PowerShell commands. `$?` has always had its quirks that made its utility questionable, but now, with `&&` and `||`, being able to set it intentionally matters. The [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917) also shows how `&&` and `||` are conceptually at odds with PowerShell's `Test-*` cmdlets.