# In Powershell, how to set $? without sending this value to the pipeline?

Tags: powershell

```
PS> gci C:\
<<here it doesn't print the value of $? as 'true' after command executes>

PS> $?
true
```

However when I try to recreate this behavior with my own powershell function I get:

```
PS> function test1 { write-host "hello"; return $true}

PS> test1
hello
true

PS> $?
true
```

What gives?  why can't I hide the return value of the function from the pipeline, and have it only written to the $? variable?

Comment: Try ```function test1 { write-host "hello";}```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: $? Contains the execution status of the last command. There is no problem here actually. If you want to see it false, you can try something like `gci some/random/path/` , then you can type `$?`, you will encounter it as false

Comment: You could also use `Write-Verbose` to have your command normally run silently, but display some useful output if you need by adding `-Verbose`.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of many automatic variables in PowerShell, you can see the full list by running:

```
get-help about_Automatic_Variables
```

The function of the `$?` is to see if the last command ran to completion or encountered an uncaught error.

For instance

```
function Throw-WhenOdd($value){
   if ($value % 2 -ne 0){
      throw "OddNumber"
   }
}


PS> Throw-WhenOdd 4
PS> $?
True
PS> Throw-WhenOdd 3
Exception:
Line |
   3 |        throw "OddNumber"
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | OddNumber
PS>$?
False
PS> #Checking the value of `$?` resets the value
# so checking a second time returns true
PS> $?
true
```

So to summarize, if you have a function or cmdlet or whatever and it can throw, you can use `$?` to see if it threw or not.  However, you have to use Throw and not Write-Error and the output is consumed the first time you check `$?`.

Comment: that's interesting... i didn't realize the interactive shell was trapping an exception to set $?.   I think this proves once again that "return" should be avoided in powershell scripts because it prints crap to your terminal that you don't want to see... the only way i've found to return values from a function is to pass in a hash and set a return value as a hash element.  then it nicely doesn't print the return value.

Comment: @pico or you could return the thing that you would otherwise write out--in the above case, 'hello'

Comment: Pico, thats a perfectly valid use of functions, passing them in to methods and toggling their values.  It's the way to dotnet passing variables as references (which results in actually and permanently changing the input object)

Comment: While it is true that a `throw` statement results in `$?` reflecting `$false` _if the runspace stays alive_, it is important to note that `throw` generates a _script_-terminating (runspace-terminating) error, so that if you call a function that uses `throw` _from inside a script_, you must use `try` / `catch` to prevent the script's instant termination, and only then can you query `$?` and only at the very start of the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

First, to clarify:

- In PowerShell, [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) - if given an argument - *outputs that argument to the success output stream*, i.e. it returns *data* - just like *implicit* output or output with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) (whose use is rarely needed) does.

  - Also note that [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is *not* designed to output *data* - it is designed for direct-to-host (console) output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).
- By contrast, in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, `return` is the function-level analog to `exit` and sets an *invisible exit code*.
- PowerShell's `$?` is an *abstract error-condition indicator* (`$true` if no errors occurred, `$false` otherwise), which is *automatically set by PowerShell itself* to indicate whether the most recently executed command or expression experienced an error condition - see details below.

---

- As of PowerShell 7.2, **you cannot *set* the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1)**; it is *set by PowerShell itself* - see the bottom section for details.

  - The need for the ability to set `$?` directly has been recognized and green-lighted in [GitHub issue #10917](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490), but has yet to be implemented.
- You **can only set it *indirectly***:

  - **Via *exit codes***, which only apply to ***external programs*** (process exit code)  ***script files* (`*.ps1`)** *if* they terminate with an `exit` statement.

    - The most recently reported exit code, which is also reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), maps to `$?` reporting `$true`, if it is `0`, and `$false` for any nonzero value.
  - For ***cmdlets* and *functions***, via ***output to PowerShell's error stream***:

    - For *binary cmdlets*, emitting at least one *non-terminating* error or a *statement-terminating error* results in `$?` reflecting `$false`
    - As of PowerShell 7.2, (by definition written-in-PowerShell) *functions* only affect `$?` if they're *advanced* functions and use the unwieldy `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` (for a non-terminating error; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469278/45375)) `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` (for a statement-terminating error) methods:

      - `Write-Error` (for non-terminating errors), unfortunately, does *not* affect `$?` - see [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629)
      - While a [`throw` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) - as shown in [FoxDeploy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437076/45375) - *does* end up setting `$?` to `$false`, it generates a *script*-terminating (runspace-terminating) error, which *requires the caller to explicitly catch the error*, with [`try / catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally), and `$?` must then be queried at the start of the `catch` block.
    - Notably, the above means:

      - Getting `$?` to reflect `$false` invariably requires producing *error output*.
      - `$?` being `$false` just tells you that *some* error occurred - it isn't a reflection of an explicit intent to signal success vs. failure of the command *as a whole*.

Comment: Love the note about why `Write-Error` doesn't affect `$?`.  That still feels wrong to me, IMHO

Comment: Thanks, @FoxDeploy - I agree that it is wrong. The issue is discussed in [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629) (I've updated the answer to link to it).