# Verify a function in PowerShell has run succesfully

Tags: function, powershell, bitlocker

I'm writing a script to backup existing bit locker keys to the associated device in Azure AD, I've created a function which goes through the bit locker enabled volumes and backs up the key to Azure however would like to know how I can check that the function has completed successfully without any errors. Here is my code. I've added a try and catch into the function to catch any errors in the function itself however how can I check that the Function has completed succesfully - currently I have an IF statement checking that the last command has run "$?  - is this correct or how can I verify please?

```
    function Invoke-BackupBDEKeys {

        ##Get all current Bit Locker volumes - this will ensure keys are backed up for devices which may have additional data drives
        $BitLockerVolumes = Get-BitLockerVolume | select-object MountPoint
        foreach ($BDEMountPoint in $BitLockerVolumes.mountpoint) {

            try {
            #Get key protectors for each of the BDE mount points on the device
            $BDEKeyProtector = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $BDEMountPoint | select-object -ExpandProperty keyprotector
            #Get the Recovery Password protector - this will be what is backed up to AAD and used to recover access to the drive if needed
            $KeyId = $BDEKeyProtector | Where-Object {$_.KeyProtectorType -eq 'RecoveryPassword'}
            #Backup the recovery password to the device in AAD
            BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint $BDEMountPoint -KeyProtectorId $KeyId.KeyProtectorId
            }
             catch {
                 Write-Host "An error has occured" $Error[0] 
            }
        }
    }     

#Run function
    Invoke-BackupBDEKeys

if ($? -eq $true) {

    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
    #No errors ocurred running the last command - reg key can be set as keys have been backed up succesfully
    $RegKeyPath = 'custom path'
    $Name = 'custom name'
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $Name -Value 1 -Force
    Exit
}
 else {
    Write-Host "The backup of BDE keys were not succesful"
    #Exit
}
```

Comment: `BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector` could throw an exception and `$?` would still return `$true` - your `catch` block is hiding this fact. If you want to handle errors further up the call stack, you'll need to re-throw the error (or throw a new one)

Comment: Why not have all the code inside the same function, the content of the `if` statement could be on your _try_ statement and the `else` in the _catch_ statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell 7.2.1, the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) has *no* meaningful value after calling a *written-in-PowerShell* function** (as opposed to a *binary cmdlet*) . (More immediately, even *inside* the function, `$?` only reflects `$false` at the very start of the `catch` block, as Mathias notes).

  - If PowerShell functions had feature parity with binary cmdlets, then emitting at least *one* (non-script-terminating) error, such as with [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error), would set `$?` in the caller's scope to `$false`, but that is currently not the case.
  - You can work around this limitation by using `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` from an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) or script, but that is quite cumbersome. The same applies to `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`, which is the only way to create a *statement*-terminating error from PowerShell code. (By contrast, the [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement generates a *script*-terminating error, i.e. terminates the entire script and its callers - unless a `try` / `catch` or `trap` statement catches the error somewhere up the call stack).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455505/45375) for more information and links to relevant GitHub issues.
- As a **workaround**, I suggest:

  - Make your function an *advanced* one, so as to enable support for the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable) - it allows you to collect all non-terminating errors emitted by the function in a self-chosen variable.

    - Note: The self-chosen variable name must be passed *without* the `$`; e.g., to collection in variable `$errs`, use `-ErrorVariable errs`; do NOT use `Error` / `$Error`, because [`$Error` is the automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) that collects all errors that occur in the entire *session*.
    - You can combine this with the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) to initially silence the errors (`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`), so you can emit them later on demand. Do NOT use `-ErrorAction Stop`, because it will render `-ErrorVariable` useless and instead abort your script as a whole.
  - You can let the errors simply occur - no need for a `try` / `catch` statement: since there is no `throw` statement in your code, your loop will continue to run even if errors occur in a given iteration.

    - Note: While it is possible to trap terminating errors inside the loop with `try` / `catch` and then *relay* them as *non-terminating* ones with `$_ | Write-Error` in the `catch` block, you'll end up with each such error *twice* in the variable passed to `-ErrorVariable`. (If you didn't relay, the errors would still be *collected*, but *not print*.)
  - After invocation, check if any errors were collected, to determine whether at least one key wasn't backed up successfully.
  - As an aside: Of course, you could alternatively make your function *output (return) a Boolean* (`$true` or `$false`) to indicate whether errors occurred, but that wouldn't be an option for functions designed to output *data*.

Here's the outline of this approach:

```sh
function Invoke-BackupBDEKeys {
  # Make the function an *advanced* function, to enable
  # support for -ErrorVariable (and -ErrorAction)
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  # ...
  foreach ($BDEMountPoint in $BitLockerVolumes.mountpoint) {

      # ... Statements that may cause errors.
      # If you need to short-circuit a loop iteration immediately
      # after an error occurred, check each statement's return value; e.g.:
      #      if (-not $BDEKeyProtector) { continue }
  }
}     

# Call the function and collect any
# non-terminating errors in variable $errs.
# IMPORTANT: Pass the variable name *without the $*.
Invoke-BackupBDEKeys -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs

# If $errs is an empty collection, no errors occurred.
if (-not $errs) {

  "No errors occurred"
  # ... 
}
else {
  "At least one error occurred during the backup of BDE keys:`n$errs"
  # ...
}
```

Here's a minimal example, which uses a script block in lieu of a function:

```sh
& {
  [CmdletBinding()] param() Get-Item NoSuchFile 
} -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
"Errors collected:`n$errs"
```

Output:

```sh
Errors collected:
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\jdoe\NoSuchFile' because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Thank you. i've been able to follow this one and have manipulated a little bit to adjust to how I understand however when including the $Error[0] in the catch i'm then unable to get this when running the function with -Error Variable $errors - this is blank and doesn't contain the errors in the catch block - see below:             
Invoke-BackupBDEKeys -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable $Errors  that $Erros variable does not contain the errors from the catch block inside the function? please advise

Comment: catch {
            # Convert the caught terminating error to a non-terminating one
            # and cotinue the loop.      
            $Errors = Write-Error -Message "Error has occured"
            #Write-Error -Message "An error has occured backing up the BDY keys to AAD"
        }
  
  
When running the function Invoke-BackupBDEKeys -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable $Errors the erros are not returned in $Erros variable

Comment: @Russeller, you must pass the variable name _without the `$`_ to `-ErrorVariable`. Don't use `-ErrorAction Stop` - it will abort your script as a whole and render `-ErrorVariable` useless. Please see my update - I've changed the approach to not use `try` / `catch` at all.

Answer (score 0):

As stated elsewhere, the try/catch you're using is what is preventing the relay of the error condition.  That is by design and the very intentional reason for using try/catch.

What I would do in your case is either create a variable or a file to capture the error info.  My apologies to anyone named 'Bob'.  It's the variable name that I always use for quick stuff.

Here is a basic sample that works:

```
$bob = (1,2,"blue",4,"notit",7)

$bobout = @{}                               #create a hashtable for errors

foreach ($tempbob in $bob) {
   $tempbob
   try {
      $tempbob - 2                          #this will fail for a string
   } catch {
      $bobout.Add($tempbob,"not a number")  #store a key/value pair (current,msg)
   }
}

$bobout                                     #output the errors
```

Here we created an array just to use a foreach.  Think of it like your $BDEMountPoint variable.

Go through each one, do what you want.  In the }catch{}, you just want to say "not a number" when it fails.  Here's the output of that:

```
-1
0
2
5

Name                           Value
----                           -----
notit                          not a number
blue                           not a number
```

All the numbers worked (you can obvious surpress output, this is just for demo).
More importantly, we stored custom text on failure.

Now, you might want a more informative error.  You can grab the actual error that happened like this:

```
$bob = (1,2,"blue",4,"notit",7)

$bobout = @{}                               #create a hashtable for errors

foreach ($tempbob in $bob) {
   $tempbob
   try {
      $tempbob - 2                          #this will fail for a string
   } catch {
      $bobout.Add($tempbob,$PSItem)         #store a key/value pair (current,error)
   }
}

$bobout
```

Here we used the current variable under inspection $PSItem, also commonly referenced as $_.

```
-1
0
2
5

Name                           Value
----                           -----
notit                          Cannot convert value "notit" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in ...
blue                           Cannot convert value "blue" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a...
```

You can also parse the actual error and take action based on it or store custom messages.  But that's outside the scope of this answer.  :)